# Set up integration manager workflow

Tags: git

I am new to git and I would like to set up a so-called "integration manager workflow" as defined per Git official website with the following diagram

[image: git workflow diagram]

As far as I understand, to do such thing I need to use the following command :

```
git --bare init
```

to make the directory my "blessed repository" and then set up read/write permissions accordingly with the OS filesystem manager.

However, one issue I have with that method is that a bare directory does not feature the actual files (e.g. main.c, method1.c, ...) but only git readable files.
I fear my management could have issue with that because they would fear the actual files could be lost/non-retrievable or not directly identifiable when looking at the directory.

Could I work with a non-bare directory while still implementing the desired workflow ? Is this advised/good practice ?

Comment: All you have to do to retrieve the blessed repository into a directory based structure is clone it - what is your manager's objection?

Comment: I can just imagine that it would bother him not to directly see the structure and not to be able to do a simple copy/paste in case it is ever needed (we are not a software developing company so we are not used to such tools and methods)

Comment: You can't copy a paragraph from a Word document either, unless you load it into Word first.

Comment: I am sure you see what I mean. Seeing a directory with only bizarre words while it is supposed to contain your files can be surprising at first for someone not aware of the system.

Comment: A Git repository consists of a commit database (usually in the `.git` directory) and of any number of work trees where commits are checked out. Because the checked out files are only a snapshot, they are not the important part of the version control system. But you are right to worry about the database. You may want to regularly back it up and check for consistency (perhaps using `git fsck`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. In Git 2.3 or later, you can use a normal, non-bare repository as your blessed repository, and set `receive.denyCurrentBranch` to `updateInstead` so that git will update the files there whenever the integration manager pushes an update. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34696771/how-does-receive-denycurrentbranch-updateinstead-interact-with-the-index

As an alternative you could use a bare repo with a 'post receive hook', i.e. a script you supply that git will run after it receives an update and use that to export the files to another directory. See https://git-scm.com/book/gr/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks